# Could not find a declaration file for module 'buffer-layout': @solana/spl-token

Tags: javascript, angular, solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I'm trying to work with @solana/spl-token lib for transferring tokens but when I tried to install and run ng serve (using Angular 11). I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'buffer-layout'. './node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try `npm install @types/buffer-layout` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'buffer-layout';`

   import {Layout} from 'buffer-layout';
```

I've tried to include

```
declare module 'buffer-layout';
```

in src/index.d.ts file but it didn't work.

I also get

```
 Namespace '"./node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
    
    7     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ToastContainerDirective, never>;
```

```
Cannot use namespace 'Layout' as a type.
    
       export const MintLayout: Layout;
```

Would be great if someone can help out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to copy another library? Sometimes just commenting out all occurrences is ok if you don't use the full subset of the package. Also make sure to export the namespaces properly, but I guess you've done this.